# place_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label, scrollbar

I am attempting to use a scrollbar with my project. I have code that creates a frame, within a canvas, within a frame, in order to put Labels onto the frame, to then be scrolled through. This is some of the code:

```
statWindow = Tk()
statWindow.title("View Statistics")
statWindow.config(bg = "grey")
statWindow.geometry('600x700')

myframe =Frame(statWindow, relief=GROOVE, width=550, height=400, bd=1)
myframe.place(x=20, y=90)

canvas = Canvas(myframe)
frame = Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar = Scrollbar(myframe, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(width=530, height=400, yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

myscrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor='nw')
frame.bind("<Configure>", myfunction)

def myfunction(event):
    global canvas
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=530,height=400)
```

I then have the code:

```
Label(frame,text="hello", height=1, width=14, bg="white").grid(row=1, column=1)
```

This works perfectly, however I really need to be using .place()
Allthough when I change the label code to:

```
Label(frame,text="hello", height=1, width=14, bg="white").place(x=10, y=10)
```

Nothing happens, as in no label is on the screen and no errors seem to occur.
However when I change the code to:

```
Label(frame,text="hello", height=1, width=14, bg="white")
Label.place(x=10, y=10)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: place_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Why can I not place a label into the frame, and how can I fix this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to call `place` on a class (`Label`). If You want to do it this way, You must assign `Label` instance to some variable and then call `place` on that variable. It works in first case because You are calling `place` on class instance, rather than class itself.
Example how it should be done:

```
label_name = Label(frame,text="hello", height=1, width=14, bg="white")
label_name.place(x=10, y=10)
```

Comment: they aren't calling `place` on a class. They are calling it on an instance.

Comment: `Label.place(x=10, y=10)` this sure looks like calling it on a class. This, `Label(frame,text="hello", height=1, width=14, bg="white").place(x=10, y=10)` on the other hand is calling it on an instance, which is working as expected.

Comment: ok, you are correct. My apologies. In one place they are doing it wrong, in one place they are doing it right. This answers the question in the title.